# ConfigureAwait(false) performance test

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, async-await, .net-4.6

Everywhere I read that I should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlocks and for performance reasons. We are using `ConfigureAwait` in our application. But might remove the ConfigureAwaits as it's causing a different thread's execution context.

The different thread's execution context is causing (sometimes) problems with translations. As the set culture in currentculture and currentUICulture is not accessible on a different execution context.

I have tested it a little bit with the code below. It did not make any performance difference. I understand it's not a good test as with this simple test there are not many threads used.

```
static async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
  stopwatch.Start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
     await Task.Delay(10);
     await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
  }
  stopwatch.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("Await: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
}

static async Task MyMethodAsyncNoAwait()
{
  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
  stopwatch.Start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
     await Task.Delay(10);
     await Task.Delay(10);
  }
  stopwatch.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
}
```

How should I test this properly? Is it a really bad idea of removing all ConfigureAwaits?

Comment: You shouldn't need `ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent deadlocks - those deadlocks will only occur in the first place if you are blocking on async code, which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: If you are testing that with something like console application - it will not make any difference anyway, because there is no context.

Comment: I would ignore the performance difference. If you're seeing different `CurrentCulture` / `CurrentUICulture` values on .NET 4.6, then that's a bug and should be reported as such.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't use `ConfigureAwait` blindly for performance. Use it when writing code (usually library code) where resuming on the same thread/synchronization context doesn't matter. If resuming on the right thread/synchronization context *does* matter, `ConfigureAwait(false)` will break your code, and then it doesn't matter how fast it could have been.

Answer (score 6):

What ever you do with `async-await` is not about performance but responsiveness and availability.

On client UIs like WinForms, WPF or UWP, it's about responsiveness. You use `async-await` on IO and CPU-bound operations to do work outside of the UI thread and `ConfigureAwait(false)` to explicitly avoid getting back to that UI thread.

On ASP.NET (.NET Framework, not .NET Core) it's about availability. You use `async-await` on IO operations to free the thread to handle other requests and use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid setting up the returning to thread as the HTTP Context thread.

But because you're always doing more work, each logical operation will take longer.

On client UIs, the user will still be able to work with the application or, at least, not get that "not responding" phrase on the title bar and task manager.

On ASP.NET, because there are more threads available to handle requests, on heavy load, it will be faster because requests are allowed to start work right away instead of being blocked in the request queue.

Comment: *On ASP.NET (.NET Framework, not .NET Core)* - why the "not .NET Core" remark? Just curious.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't have context affinity and thinks like `HttpContext.Current` that are managed by a synchronization context.